# How can I restructure this large PostgreSQL 9.3 table to be indexed and searched more efficiently from a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, search, hstore

I introduced a design flaw into this application I'm working on. The problem domain involves matching a `Product` against what is essentially a sparse matrix of 50 possible attributes per `Customer`. There are millions and millions of rows. So to restate:

```
Product has_many ProductAttributes
Customer has_many ProductAttributes
```

A `Product` will have a different set of `ProductAttributes` for each `Customer`.

So I have this table of 50 million rows, and the vast, vast majority of the fields are empty. It is painful to look at. Here are some of my problems.

- Each product averages only about 4 attributes.
- In order to make the table case-insensitive searchable, I used `citext` in all of the attribute columns.
- The first 3 attributes are indexed, and have wildcard searches performed on them.

I would much rather redo this whole situation by using either HStore or JSON fields. But I am concerned about my ability to perform searches against either. Can fulltext searches be done against either one of these? Would HStore key-value pairs limit me? Currently, each `ProductAttribute` can have only one value, but I can envision a scenario in which I could use an Array of values in at least one of them. Not a deal killer though.

If I can search on JSON and/or HStore, which is the best one to use considering I am using ActiveRecord from a Rails 3.2 application?

Another alternative would be to break out `ProductAttributes` into a `detail` table:

```
Product has_many CustomerProducts
Customer has_many CustomerProducts
CustomerProducts has_many ProductAttributes
```

So if a Product had only 3 or 4 attributes for a specific `Customer`, there would be 3 or 4 records in `ProductAttributes`. And I could just search the value column for the `ProductAttribute`, returning the `CustomerProdct` parent record.

So three possible approaches:

```
HStore
JSON
Detail table
```

Thank you for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely query Hstore, and I think it might be a good solution short of going for a higher normal form in your Schema design, which can be hard if you aren't a Database person.

You can do a query like:

```
Product.where("attributes -> 'Color' = 'Blue'")
Product.where("attributes -> 'Size' LIKE '%L%'") #finds 'Large' and 'Long' for ex.
```

Check out this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore?view=asciicast), full disclosure, its a pro cast (costs $)

However, do consider trying to get you Schema into maybe [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) to solve it in a more databasey way.

Comment: I'm actually a reformed Oracle DBA (20 yrs), it's just that it seemed expensive (and complicated) to do between 4 and 7 AR inserts per CustomerProduct, especially on bulk loads. I'll check out the RailsCast, I am a member out there. But wouldn't the JSON functionality be like Hstore plus? Also checking out `textacular` gem and whether I can create full text search indexes on individual JSON fields.

Comment: Found this post by the Thoughbot guys too: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/implementing-multi-table-full-text-search-with-postgres

Comment: Hum... I haven't used textacular, but it looks cool. Check out this HStore vs. Json [comparison](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/07/03/hstore-vs-json/) its a pretty quick read. FWIW, HStore performs better for now on searches. For me, Hstore is great for internal non-document string data. Json is great for documents, heterogeneous data, and data from external json sources(obviously?).  Yeah, I guess higher normal forms do have high batch insert costs...

Comment: Thanks I saw that today. I was all set for Hstore then I saw his closing statement ;-)